# Query not running

Tags: php, sql

I wonder if anyone can spot what is going wrong here? The first query has been tested and is working because I can print out the $groups array, but the 2nd one will not run. When I hard code the $groups array it runs fine.

```
require ('mysqli_connect.php'); // Connect to the db.
echo '<p>If no record is shown, this is because you had an incorrect or missing entry in the search form.<br>Click the back button on the browser and try again</p>';

//Coming from another page
$uninum=$_POST['uninum'];
$sname=$_POST['sname'];

$groups = array ( );
$count = count ($groups);

$q1 = "SELECT `groupid` FROM `groups` 
         WHERE `uninum` = '".$uninum."'";
$result1 = @mysqli_query($dbcon,$q1);
while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array ($result1, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

    $groups[] = $row1['groupid'];

}


for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){

    $q = "SELECT participants.sname, participants.uninum, 
                 groups.groupid 
          FROM participants 
             INNER JOIN groups ON 
                participants.uninum = groups.uninum 
          WHERE groups.groupid ='".$groups[$i]."'";         

    $result = @mysqli_query ($dbcon, $q); // Run the query.
    if ($result) { // If it ran, display the records.
        // Table header.
        echo '<table>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Edit</b></td>
            <td><b>Surnname</b></td>
            <td><b>University ID</b></td>
            <td><b>Group</b></td>
        </tr>';
        // Fetch and display the records:
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            echo '<tr>
            <td><a href="edit_group_member.php?uninum=' . $row['uninum'] . '">Edit</a></td>
            <td>' . $row['sname'] . '</td>
            <td>' . $row['uninum'] . '</td>
            <td>' . $row['groupid'] . '</td>
            </tr>';
        }
        echo '</table>'; // Close the table.
        mysqli_free_result ($result); // Free up the resources. 
        echo "<br><br>";
    } else { // If it did not run OK.
        // Public message:
        echo '<p class="error">The current users could not be retrieved. We apologize for any inconvenience.</p>';
        // Debugging message:
        echo '<p>' . mysqli_error($dbcon) . '<br><br>Query: ' . $q . '</p>';

    }
}
```

Comment: My guess is that if you remove the `@` you'll see the errors. If not, add error checking, such as `or die(mysqli_error())` to your queries. Or you can find the issues in your current error logs.

Comment: Then again anybody could have put a sql injection string in `$uninum` and dropped your tables ;).

Comment: Why are you doing `$count = count ($groups);` ***before*** filling the `$groups` array with values?

Comment: Maybe it would be a good idea to provide some details about the failure, eg. where it exactly happens, output of `$dbcon->error` and the like, don't you think so?

Comment: Please try and format your code so its readable, without having to scroll furthur right than ghengis khan

Comment: You are setting the value of `$count` -> `$count = count ($groups);` **BEFORE** you add any values to the array in the loop -> `while(...){$groups[] = $row1['groupid'];}` so `$count` will always be `0`, so your 2nd loop will never run.

Comment: ProTip: ***Never*** use the `@` symbol before a function.  If there's an error, you should be catching and handling it, not just ignoring it.

Comment: Thanks for the tips and advice:). Rocket Hazmat - That was what was causing it. Many thanks!

Comment: Another good reason for not setting count variables when you could simply do `for ($i = 0; $i < count($groups); $i++) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing `@` with `mysqli_query` also `$groups` array will not start looping until your count is greater then zero.
if you `var_dump($count)` it will return zero.

```
$count = count ($groups);
var_dump($count);
```

You should `count` array after the `query` returns result set, right after ending `while loop`

```
$q1 = "SELECT `groupid` FROM `groups` WHERE `uninum` = '".$uninum."'";
$result1 = @mysqli_query($dbcon,$q1);
while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array ($result1, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $groups[] = $row1['groupid'];
}
// count here 
$count = count ($groups);
```

Comment: Count will result 1 .

Comment: @DanishEnam empty array count is always zero.

Answer (score 3):

```
$groups = array ( );
$count = count ($groups);
```

$count is always equal zero